# Change event for multiple text boxes

Tags: vba

I have written single change event for multiple text boxes using class Module but what I observed is in my 'oControl' Me.Controls give False and not the control. Is there any other way I can do that?

```
Private m_oCollectionOfEventHandlers As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set m_oCollectionOfEventHandlers = New Collection
    Dim oControl As Control
    For Each oControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(oControl) = "TextBox" Then
            Dim oEventHandler As Class1
            Set oEventHandler = New Class1
            Set oEventHandler.TextBox = oControl
            m_oCollectionOfEventHandlers.Add oEventHandler
        End If

    Next oControl
End Sub

'CLASS MODULE
Private WithEvents m_oTextBox As TextBox
Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox As TextBox)
    Set m_oTextBox = oTextBox
End Property
Private Sub m_oTextBox_Change()
MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try declare oControl as Object instead

Comment: You are just seeing the value of the control's default property.  You should be able to ignore this and continue.  Are you getting any actual errors from this?

Comment: I want to give limit to my text box between 0 to 400 and in my case there are around 100 tetboxes

Comment: my texbox change event is not being fired